# More precise control over QGIS symbology classification

Tags: qgis, classification

In QGIS, I would like to classify my graduated symbology by standard déviations, as such:

[image]

. However, I find that the behaviour seems erratic or hard to control, and I can't choose the number of classes like I do with other classification methods (i.e. quantiles). Is there a way to have a more precise control over how many classes (and deviations from the mean) are used to classify the data set?

For instance, I would like to classify this distributio, by steps of 0.5 std devotions. So that the scale would range from < -1.5 Std Dev to > +3.5 Std Dev :

[image]